# How to randomize the value properly?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers

Currently, I've managed to create a basic sparse matrix using this code:

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae902be1d7118c2d)

Then the output look like this:

```
Insert: (83,86,77,)

Insert: (15,93,35,)

Insert: (86,92,49,)

Insert: (21,62,27,)

Insert: (90,59,63,)
```

I've 2 problems here:

1. How can I remove the last `,` and add space after each comma. I've tried `cout << arr[i][k] << ', '` but it's not working.
2. Currently all the value of `row` and `col` of this matrix is between 0 to 100. Since my matrix size is set to `5`. How can I make the `row` and `col` value follow this size?

My expected output look something like this:

```
Insert: (5, 1, 84)

Insert: (1, 4, 39)

Insert: (2, 3, 16)

Insert: (4, 2, 13)

Insert: (5, 5, 100)
```

Comment: Did you write that code yourself? Because the changes needed are pretty obvious.

Comment: *"`<< ', '` but it's not working"* - C++ uses single quotes for single-character literals, and double-quotes for string literals: to have both a comma and a space you need a string literal: `", "`.

Answer (score 0):

To change your array size : you change thisline:

```
int** arr = constructSparseMatrix(size,3);
```

to

```
int** arr = constructSparseMatrix(size,5);
```

for the printingn just check if you are printing the last element of your array or not:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
      cout << arr[i][k];
      if(k<4) cout<<', ';
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but maybe you misunderstood my question. My expected result for `row` and `col` is from `1` to `5`, not the `size`, currently it's `(83,86,77)` but I want `(1,5,77)` for example. You can check my demo and my question again.